# Flex: selectable text in DataGridColumn?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I make text selectable (so I can copy) in a DataGridColumn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom component with a selectable label and assign it to the itemRenderer property of the data grid column:

DGCRenderer.mxml

```
<mx:Label xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" selectable="true">
</mx:Label>
```

Main.mxml

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" itemRenderer="DGCRenderer"/>
```

Comment: ok thanks, had hoped to avoid creating a custom itemRenderer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an even better way to do it.  Just sub-class the default DataGridItemRenderer and set the selectable flag to true.

```
package com.renderers
{
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridItemRenderer;

    public class SelectableDataGridItemRenderer extends DataGridItemRenderer
    {
        public function SelectableDataGridItemRenderer()
        {
            super();
            this.selectable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In your mxml you'd then do something like this:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" itemRenderer="com.renderers.SelectableDataGridItemRenderer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't we simply use the mx.controls.Text as the item renderer. It serves the purpose correctly.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" itemRenderer="mx.controls.Text"/>
```